# Best way to merge a 3rd party source code with local modifications in git

Tags: git

Our company has bought access to the source code of a 3rd party library developer.  We get copies of their source every time they have a new release.  However, we also make some mods to their source code that doesn't necessarily go upstream to their code base.

I'm thinking that we should be able to make a git repository off of ours which handles only their source code.  We would then be able to have our modified source code then do a type of rebase to keep it in sync.

An issue I see with this is that I believe that rebasing is an operation that occurs on a branch, moving the branch point from where it is to further along the branch it is on.  Any merge conflicts will be then pointed out.  However, I'm not sure how this could be done which would keep our repository the main branch as well as theirs.

A thought that I have is to have a separate repository for their source code (let's call it `3rd-party`), which we would branch off of with our modifications, and have their source code as the trunk.  We could then rebase our branch off of that trunk.  Then, in our main repository, we would link to our branch of `3rd-party`.  It is this last point that my hands go all wavy as I say *Abra-kadabra!*

Is what I am suggesting a possible solution?  Or is there some other way to do what I am asking for?

Please forgive me if I'm not using the terms right.  We've only moved to git in the last month and I'm still learning.

## Edit

Just to be clear, we have already have their source code with our changes.  So, I'm not even sure what the best way to bring in their old source code where we have successfully already merged to so that we would have a common base.  Our code is to be the trunk and the trunk is to be our development branch.  We have already setup our system in this way and have some tools that are currently setup assuming this setup.  We also have more than just one library.

Our current "process", which was migrated from TFS, is to

1. remove any deleted files (I guess I could delete them all, and only copy the  relevant *.vcxproj* and *.vcxproj.filters* files)
2. add new source/resource/other files
3. do a diff on the changes and cherry pick (manually copy and paste our code over to the new code) the additions we have made to move into the new code base.
4. verify changes haven't broken things too badly and fix anything that has been broken.
5. Check in changes.

Of course, step 3 is the most problematic, and I'm hoping that doing this will simplify things as there would be a common ancestor.

I've written some scripts that will automatically stage files that don't have dany of our changes in them in an attempt to simplify this process.

## Second thought

As rebasing appears to complicate things, perhaps I could just make a repository that only houses the `3rd-party` library.  I would use that repository for only merging as suggested by @Mark Adelsberger answer.  Then I could just copy off the HEAD of that repository into our main repository.

This would mean that they would be two separate and distinct repositories with no linkage between them, but might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED** based on discussion in comments.  A couple new notes about project structure before I get into it, though.

If you have commits prior to the first vendor source drop, that at least suggests the possibility that you have significant code files of your own, in addition to modified versions of vendor code.  That isn't what I'd picked up from the original question.

If that's the case, you may want to put the vendor code in a specific subdirectory (`./vendor/`), which was not reflected in the script I originally provided.  (If not, how will you avoid the possibility that they add a new file at a path/filename you'd been using for one of your files?)

So in any case, wherever I use the command

```
cp -R /path/to/latest/source/drop/* .
```

my assumption is that the code is laid out "correctly" at `/path/to/latest/source/drop`.

---

**Original answer**

Every time you rebase (or in any way rewrite) a branch, clean-up is required for every repo that already had a copy of that branch.  Since I would expect all of your dev team to have clones with the branches containing your local modifications to this source base, I do not recommend rebasing as a routine part of the workflow.

Instead, just merge.

The sales pitch for rebase is that it produces a clean, linear history.  Sometimes that's useful, though it usually has costs.  But in this case, it's simply not plausible.  You cannot reasonably produce a single linear history containing your changes and those of another organization, wherein they don't incorporate some of the changes you're making on an ongoing basis, and you *do* get the changes they make on an ongoing basis.  (Heck, you can't even control whether their changes come to you as a linear history to start with.)

More to the point, you'd spend a ton of unnecessary effort trying to do it, even if conditions line up just right and you somehow make it happen.

What I would do is this:  Maintain your code using whatever branching strategy works for your team.  Add to that a "vendor" branch.  Your modifications should never affect the vendor branch, but you'll merge from the vendor branch to your development branch (details perhaps varying based on your exact branching strategy).

So for example, suppose you have a `dev` branch that accumulates your work for the upcoming release.  You do an initial import of the vendor code, creating commit `V1`.  Then you branch from that to create your `dev` branch and start making changes.

```
V1 <--(vendor)
  \
   A -- B -- C <--(dev)
```

Now some time goes by and you get another source drop from the vendor.  Check out the `vendor` branch, then replace the working version with the new source drop.

(The below assumes that there's no reason for the `vendor` branch work tree to contain any files other than those provided by the vendor.  In practice you may find some things, like a .gitignore or .gitattributes file, to be useful; and in any case you need to make sure the .git directory isn't deleted.  So you may want a more "careful" script in place of the `rm` command I show here...)

```
git checkout vendor
rm -rf *
cp -R /path/to/latest/source/drop/* .
git add .
git commit -m "20xx-xx-xx source drop from $vendor"
```

yielding

```
V1 -- V2 <--(vendor)
  \
   A -- B -- C <--(dev)
```

And now you can merge from `vendor` to `dev`.

```
git checkout dev
git merge vendor
```

To calculate the merge, git will figure out that `V1` is the merge base, and will determine what's changed on `vendor` since `V1`.  So you may get conflicts, and indeed this could get ugly since you presumably can't prevent the vendor from doing wild refactoring on a whim, but it will be as easy as any other way.

```
V1 ----------- V2 <--(vendor)
  \              \ 
   A -- B -- C -- M<--(dev)
```

Then this cycle just continues; you keep developing, and whenever you import `Vn` git will realize due to previous merges that `V(n-1)` is the merge base.

---

**UPDATE**

In comments you mention that you already have a repo set up with some of your code in it.  That doesn't prevent using the above approach, but it introduces some questions - because if your project is based on modification of vendor code, then what do versions before the first source drop look like?

I see a couple things that could mean, so feel free to jump to whichever section best describes your situation (or, if none of these is right, please clarify):

***Does it mean you just didn't commit the original vendor code drop?***

(*Update 2:* Based on comments, it sounds like that's the situation.  The first approach I suggested for this involves a history rewrite; you've stated that you don't want to rewrite history.  That's up to you, so here's another alternative.  This creates a slightly "weirder" history, but is simple to execute and will work fine going forward.)

As with all the options I've posted, you start by creating a "clean" history for the vendor branch.

```
git checkout --orphan vendor
rm -rf *
cp -R /path/to/latest/source/drop/* .
git add .
git commit -m "initial source drop from $vendor"
```

Now you'll "fake merge" this into your existing `dev` branch, so that git will understand it as a merge base when you add future versions to the `vendor` branch.

```
git checkout dev
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -s ours vendor
```

The `-s ours` specifies the "ours" merge strategy, which says "don't change the content I already have in the `HEAD` commit".  This will yield

```
            V1 <--(vendor)
              \
A -- B -- C -- M <--(dev)
```

where `M` has the same "content" (`TREE`) as `C`, but recognizes `V1` as a parent commit.  You can continue with the originally-described approach from here, as `V1` will serve as the merge base when you bring in `V2`.

It's worth noting that you should probably only use `-s` when the default merge strategy would create a merge conflict - which it would here, so no problem.  If the default merge strategy were able to resolve the merge, then using an alternative merge strategy creates an "evil merge", in which changes (relative to both parents) are "hidden" in ways that can confuse both the user and some git commands.  For this purpose, it should be fine though.

That said, the claim that a rewrite would be "risky" is questionable for two reasons.  (1) You don't have to replace origin until you've validated the result, so the organizational risk is zero; at worst it takes time (and so will any alternative).  (2) The type of merge approach you describe in comments has more moving parts, so is harder to reason about - which is why I say something *might* go wrong (but can't really predict exactly what).  A rewrite is less familiar, but that's not the same as "riskier".

With that in mind, I've preserved the original rewrite approach here:

Create a second "root" commit in your repo.  Same caveats about the `rm` command apply as above.

```
git checkout --orphan vendor
rm -rf *
cp -R /path/to/latest/source/drop/* .
git add .
git commit -m "initial source drop from $vendor"
```

Now you have

```
V1 <--(vendor)

A -- B -- C <--(dev)
```

Since I'm assuming at the moment that `A` already contains a modified version of the vendor code, you'd just want to re-parent `A`.

This will be a history rewrite, but you need only do it once.  My recommended approach for this type of rewrite is to have everyone push all of their code to the shared remote, then discard their clones, then you do the rewrite, then everyone creates new clones.

The rewrite would be done using `git filter-branch`.  You'll need to find the commit ID of `V1`.  You can get this from a command like

```
git log -n1 --format=%H vendor
```

It will be a 40-character string of hex digits.  Then the rewrite command would look something like

```
git filter-brnach --parent-filter  'sed "s/^\$/-p <commit-ID-from-above-command>/"' -- dev
```

If you have multiple branches, then were I said `dev` you'd want to name all of your branches (except `vendor`).  If you have lots of branches, I guess you could use `--all` instead of typing it all out, but then you need a slightly more sophisticated `--parent-filter` to distinguish your root from the vendor root; see the `git filter-branch` docs in that case.

If your history contains tags, you'll want them to move, so add a `--tag-name-filter`

```
git filter-brnach --parent-filter  'sed "s/^\$/-p <commit-ID-from-above-command>/"' --tag-name-filter cat -- dev
```

The result of this would be

```
V1 <--(vendor)
  \
   A' -- B' -- C' <--(dev)
```

where `A'` replaces `A`, etc.  The important point is that you have the "pure" vendor code on which `A'` was based to use as a merge base for the next vendor source drop.   From here everything works as I originally described.

***Or does it mean that you have your own code and are adding the vendor code to it?***

In this case, your existing commits would contain no vendor code; so the fix is similar, but likely simpler.  There's probably no need to do a rewrite.

(You *could* do a rewrite, particularly if you want the vendor code to appear in the commits that already exist in your history.  But this would have to be done via rebase instead of reparenting, and that opens up a whole new can of worms.  If you can get by with the vendor code being added in after the initial history, it's much simpler; if you need instructions on how to rewrite the vendor code into the existing history, let us know and we can add additional information.)

You'll still want to create a "clean" history for the vendor branch.

```
git checkout --orphan vendor
rm -rf *
cp -R /path/to/latest/source/drop/* .
git add .
git commit -m "initial source drop from $vendor"
```

But now you'll just merge this into your existing `dev` branch, so that you'll have the vendor files from that point onward.

```
git checkout dev
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories vendor
```

As long as none of your files have the same path/filename as any vendor file, this merge will go smoothly, yielding

```
            V1 <--(vendor)
              \
A -- B -- C -- M <--(dev)
```

and then you can continue with the originally-described approach from here, as `V1` will serve as the merge base when you bring in `V2`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  The `dev` branch is supposed to exist prior to the `vendor` branch, right?  And we are reading these graphs from left to right as forward in time?  Then is `A` supposed to be left of `V1`?  Also, is the `vendor` branch is to only contain the vendor changes?  And those changes will be merged into the main branch with our local changes?

Comment: Left-to-right is forward in time. V1 is the first code you get from the vendor. A is the first modification you make to that code, B is the second, etc. Your main branch here is dev. When the vendor ships V2, you put it in the vendor branch, then do `git merge vendor` from the dev branch. This will bring in the vendor’s changes to your branch.

Comment: Oh, well, that may be a problem as we have already setup our git system such that our code is the base branch (trunk).  How does that affect this description?  Sounds like the roles are reversed w.r.t. what you have said.  We also have other libraries as well, so having multiple base vendor branches doesn't make sense.

Comment: I do agree with your comment about rebasing.  It seems to be a lot of hassle with not a huge amount of gain.  Our company has stopped that process for now, esp since we are all still nubes.

Comment: @Adrian - It's unclear to me how you have a first version of modified vendor code that isn't preceded by the first vendor code drop, but to your question: no, it doesn't matter.  If your existing commit contains vendor code, though, there are extra steps you probably should take to help with the merge of the next vendor drop.  Will update.

Comment: So, we already have a version of merged code in our repo in a separate dir.  I'm thinking I will have to: ***1.*** Make a branch `3rd`, where I'll del our merged code, add their code just prior to our merged code and commit.  That will be our base.  ***2.*** Branch off of that `3rd-dev` where we add our merged code and commit. ***3.*** Go back to `3rd`, del their old code, add their new code and commit. ***4.***  Merge `3rd` to `3rd-dev` and commit. ***5.*** Merge `3rd-dev` to `main`.  ***Q:*** Once done, I will need to keep `3rd` for vendor updates, but do I need to keep `3rd-dev`?

Comment: @Adrian - revising my comment after rereading yours. I think what you describe, while it uses "simpler" commands, is more complex overall than what I suggest above and has the potential for something to go wrong when merging back to `main`.  If you try it and it does work, then you would not need `3rd-dev` going forward; because the current version on `3rd` would be reachable from `main` you could merge future versions of `3rd` into `main` directly

Comment: Hmmm.  Well, I am not going to rewrite history.  That would be too risky for our organization, especially since we are very new to git and there are many devs.  However, I'm not exactly sure if any of your approaches directly applies to my use case.  What could go wrong when merging back to `main`?

Comment: @Adrian - No offense, but "I'm new at this, so I think the idea I came up with would be safer than what you recommend" is not the most well-reasoned argument I've ever heard.  Nonetheless, I've updated to add another alternative that avoids the history rewrite while merging in the vendor version more simply/safely than the way you propose.

Comment: Although "I'm new to this", so is the company that I work for and they are risk averse, as they should be when it deals with their IP.  We have already had a minor hiccup with one of our developers rewriting history and we can't tell where that occurred nor who did it.  Though I appreciate your help, you don't know where I work, who my managers are or anything about the situation that I am in.  I appreciate your help, so thanks for that.  It has helped with my understanding of git.  Best of luck.

Comment: I'm not a git expert, but no matter what you do, as long as you don't think of the repo as a backup, and actually back up the repo, assuming your developers keep their local repos, you could minimize the damage caused by a mistake and the work it takes to rebuild the history, with hourly incremental backups especially in a shop with more than 1 developer. By recommitting, in the right order, from local repos you could fix the history. Of course this becomes exponentially harder with each additional developer since the order the commits happen is important with very active developers.