# Updating git branch from zipped files

Tags: git

I am still kinda new to git and I'm not sure how properly to handle this kind of input.  I am fine working in git on my own changes and branches but not sure how to handle the master that come in from a file.

I have a base software that I am modifying that come from a group, but they release it in a zip file containing everything.  I had initialized my master branch on this then branched off my changes from that.  This master software changed versions recently so they released a whole new zip file from what I was working on. I want to just update that  master branch to this new version but wasn't sure how to do that.  In this new contents it adds and removes files and directories so if I just copied the new files in it might keep files that were supposed to be removed.

Am I just supposed to delete everything and start over in that branch?  Won't that delete git files down in the tree?  Would this remove the change tracking?  I tried with a copy of my repo but I think I did something wrong and git didn't work anymore, so I must be doing something wrong.  Is there a better/correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the master that come in from a file"?

Comment: He means he used that "zip download" feature on GitHub/GitLab. Ie not master, but a snapshot of it.

Comment: I mean that the source files that I am building on are coming from a zip file from the vendor that include a board support package and some source code.  They don't release via git or anything, they just provide a zip file containing everything.  I had used this as my master branch and just made a few feature and "implementation" branches off of it to add my own code on top of theirs. Now that they have an update I need to fix this baseline for all my work to the new version.  Sorry if this isn't the right way to set things up or describe it, but I really don't know what I'm doing I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in Git command to deal with your situation.  If there were, it might be named `git vendor-import` or something along those lines.  There's also no single best way to deal with this.  If there were, `git vendor-import`, or whatever its name might be, would probably exist.  Still, there are some common themes.

#### Draw a diagram of what happens when you get a new vendor release

You have, in essence, a series of snapshots that come from a vendor, on which you build your own software.  Let's draw this situation:

```
V1.0---------V1.1  <-- new release from vendor
  \
   A--B--C   <-- your versions
```

Each time you get a new release from the vendor, it's a full snapshot of the entire set of files they intend for you to have.  (Perhaps they are not called "version 1.0" and "version 1.1"; if not, feel free to use some other names in the diagram above.)

#### Draw a diagram of more-typical Git use

Now let's consider what a set of Git branches and commits might look like.  Remember that a Git commit *is* a snapshot of files, even though you will generally *view* commits as diffs, and make new commits by extracting some snapshot, then modifying some files and making the next snapshot.  We start with some initial snapshot—maybe it has only a `README` file, even—and grow from there:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

(These uppercase letters stand in for Git hash IDs, which look random rather than sequential, but still identify each commit.)

Once we have enough of a system built up to be useful, we might start making branches for particular features or ideas:

```
A--...--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

The attachment of the special name `HEAD` indicates that we have commit `J`, via branch `feature`, checked out right now—that's the set of files we have to work on.  (The files inside the snapshots are read-only and de-duplicated across all commits, so these are *copies* of the snapshot, not the snapshot itself.)

At this point maybe we need to fix a high priority bug on `master`, so we run `git checkout master` or (since Git 2.23) `git switch master`, which removes the copies of the files from commit `J` and gets out copies of the files from commit `H`:

```
A--...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

We are now working with the `master` / commit-`H` files.  We fix the high priority bug and make a new commit as usual; let's call this new commit `K`:

```
A--...--G--H--K   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

Now we can go back to working on our feature with `git checkout feature` or `git switch feature`, which removes all of `K`'s files from our work area and replaces them with `J`'s files:

```
A--...--G--H--K   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

When we work with an *upstream* repository (via GitHub or other provider *fork* mechanisms), this gets a bit more complicated, but fundamentally, a Git repository simply holds *commits*, plus some ways to find the *latest* commits.  Here, the two latest commits are `K`, on `master`, and `J`, on `feature`.  Running `git checkout name` or `git switch name` gets you that latest commit.  From there, you build up new work and eventually run `git commit` to make a *new* commit, which automatically extends whichever branch the special name `HEAD` is attached-to.

#### Compare these diagrams

In a typical vendor-less Git setup, or a setup where you get an entire Git repository from your vendor, you will have some sort of main or vendor branch, and then have your own branches where you have customized their software:

```
...--o--o   <-- main
         \
          o--o--o   <-- customized (HEAD)
```

In your particular case, where you got a drop from the vendor that we call `V1.0`, you have their drop, which we can call `vendor`, and your customizations:

```
V1.0   <-- vendor
  \
   o--o--o   <-- customized (HEAD)
```

You now get a new drop from the vendor.  All you need to do now is put that in as a new vendor commit on your `vendor` branch:

```
V1.0--------V1.1   <-- vendor
  \
   o--o--o   <-- customized (HEAD)
```

and you're looking at a typical Git setup, albeit with one very *big* change to go from `V1.0` to `V1.1`, instead of a series of smaller changes that are easier to debug, digest, understand, and so on.

The only real trick is dropping `V1.1` in.  If you have the branch name all set, this is pretty easy, as long as you don't mind messing with your existing work-tree (cleaning it out so that there are no stray files, etc):

```
git status                    # make sure everything is committed
git clean -dfx                # remove all build products, etc

git checkout vendor           # or `git switch vendor`
git rm -r .                   # remove all the old files
unzip path/to/vendor/drop     # unpack the new drop
git add .                     # add all the new files
git commit                    # make a new commit on the vendor branch
git tag [options] vendor-v1.1 # optionally, tag each vendor drop too
```

(There is a slightly more efficient way to do this with lower level Git operations—and it might be better to use a separate work-tree to avoid messing with any in-progress work—but that would be something to do in a `vendor-import` tool anyway.)

See also [Best way to merge a 3rd party source code with local modifications in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47998535/1256452).

Comment: I think that does what I needed.  I just wasn't sure how to look this up or even describe it.  You have the right idea, it is snapshots I'm getting and needing to use as my base for customization.  I'm probably in over my head but I'm trying to figure this out.  I don't have anyone around who would know any of this stuff so I really appreciate your help.  It seems to work on a backup so it sounds like the right thing.